# executing and capturing output of java execution from python

Tags: java, python, hadoop, jar

I have written a program in java using hadoop api. So, the output of that java code is a jar.. say foo.jar

To run that jar in hadoop, I do

```
hadoop jar foo.jar org.foo.bar.MainClass input output
```

And this starts a long hadoop task (say few minutes).

While the job is running.. hadoop gives me the progress.. like

```
Map 0%, Reduce 0%
Map 20%, Reduce 0%
....
```

and so on..
After the job ends, hadoop spits out bunch of statistics (like input size, splits, records etc).. 
All this is done from command line..

Now, what I am trying to do is.. call this program from python (using simple system execution..)

But what I want is .. when i run this python code.. I also want to show some of these statistics..but not all..

So, what I am looking for is to a way to capture these stats which are being displayed by that jar execution and process it inside python and display that processed stats..

For example..By default, hadoop shows me..

```
Map 0%, Reduce 0%
Map 20%, Reduce 0%
```

...

And so on..

And maybe what I have is...

```
def progress_function(map,reduce):

      return sum([map,reduce])/2.0
```

And I am displaying on the command prompt..

```
progress so far:0
progress so far:10

and so on..
```

So long story short.. I have a jar of java program.. which when executed spits out some stats.. i want to run this java jar from python.. and then capture these stats... and then modify them inside python and display these python stats to the user.

Comment: Sounds like simple piping

Answer (score 1):

You want to use shell pipes for this type of problem for a number of reasons. It makes it more flexible for a design perspective, calling out processes from python can be awkward, and more importantly piping makes it easy for the python script to consume the output while the programming is running.

```
hadoop jar foo.jar org.foo.bar.MainClass input output 2>&1 | python myscript.py
```

Have `myscript.py` take in input via `stdin` and just output normally with `print`.

Note that the `2>&1` in the shell command redirects stderr to stdout since piping moves the output from stdout, not stderr.